# Java - Maven - Cucumber: Feature file is not able to run

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, gherkin

I need some help with running a feature file.

This is the skeleton of the Maven project:

[image: Skeleton]

This is my pom.xml file:

```
 <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <junit.version>5.0.0</junit.version>
    <selenium.version>3.4.0</selenium.version>
    <surefire.version>2.12.4</surefire.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.25</slf4j.version>
    <log4j.version>2.9.1</log4j.version>
    <testng.version>6.11</testng.version>
    <apache.poi.version>3.16</apache.poi.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-ie-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-edge-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-opera-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-safari-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>${apache.poi.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>${apache.poi.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>${testng.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>${appium.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.stephenc.monte</groupId>
        <artifactId>monte-screen-recorder</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.11</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And, when I try to run my Feature file, the error is below:

```
Exception in thread "main" cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Unrecognized plugin: org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvm2SMFormatter
at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions$ParsedPluginData.addPluginName(RuntimeOptions.java:372)
at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.parse(RuntimeOptions.java:125)
at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.<init>(RuntimeOptions.java:85)
at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.<init>(RuntimeOptions.java:78)
at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.<init>(RuntimeOptions.java:70)
at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:31)
at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)
```

Process finished with exit code 1

My java version is:

java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)

This is my RUN/Debug configuration:

[image: Run/Debug config]

I'm not able to run the Feature file and with this, I cannot run any related with Cucumber.
Can you please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems to be something with the --format option in your config. Maybe try without that to see if it runs and go from there? Also this link might be helpful ? https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206750055-Cucumber-Plugin-Run-Configurations

Comment: You need to look at cleaning up the pom.xml.
There is a mixture of cucumber 1.2.5 and cucumber 3. Either choose the old info.cukes or the new io.cucumber.
There is no need for so many selenium related dependencies. Just use something like to get everything related to selenium.

    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
     <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
     <version>3.11.0</version>
    </dependency>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I was missing a decent runner for Cucumber features like this:

```
    @CucumberOptions(features = {"src/test/resource/features"},
                 glue={"stepdefs"},
                 monochrome = true,
                 tags = {"~@Ignore"},
                 plugin = {"pretty","html:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber-pretty",
                           "json:target/cucumber-reports/CucumberTestReport.json",
                           "rerun:target/cucumber-reports/rerun.txt",
                           "usage:target/cucumber-usage.json"}
)
public class TestRunner extends ExtendedTestNGRunner{
    private TestNGCucumberRunner testNGCucumberRunner;

    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setUpClass() throws Exception {
        testNGCucumberRunner = new TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass());
    }

    @Test(groups = "cucumber", description = "Runs Cucumber Feature", dataProvider = "features")
    public void feature(CucumberFeatureWrapper cucumberFeature) {
        testNGCucumberRunner.runCucumber(cucumberFeature.getCucumberFeature());
    }

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] features() {
        return testNGCucumberRunner.provideFeatures();
    }

    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void tearDownClass() throws Exception {
        testNGCucumberRunner.finish();
    }
}
```

That was all. Thanks evrybody for your time!!!

Answer (score 0):

Several things:

1. Remove duplicate dependencies
2. Make sure you are using the *same* Cucumber version for all Cucumber dependencies. Otherwise, Cucumber might behave unexpectedly.
   It's helpful to use a version number like this `<version>${cucumber.version}</version>` for each dependency, so you can update it in one place and are sure all dependencies are using the same version (note that you are using this in several places, but I don't see the cucumber version defined anywhere).
3. Update to a newer version of Cucumber; v1.2.5 is quite old at this point. Current version is 3.0.2. 
   **Note:** `<groupId>info.cukes</groupId>` was updated to `<groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>`
4. Remove unnecessary dependencies; afaik `cucumber-core` and `gherkin` are not needed as they are transitive dependencies of other libraries.

Comment: Hi everybody: Now, I did everything that you wrote, but now I'm facing the next issue: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface cucumber.api.TestCase, but class was expected
 at org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvm2SMFormatter.handleTestCaseStarted(CucumberJvm2SMFormatter.java:80)
 at org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvm2SMFormatter.access$000(CucumberJvm2SMFormatter.java:17)
 at org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvm2SMFormatter$1.receive(CucumberJvm2SMFormatter.java:32)
 at org.jetbrains.plugins.cucu

Comment: When I update the dependencies with <version>${cucumber.version}</version> and I add the imports to the StepDefs class, the POM suffers modifications.